# Unable to get the html paths working as desired

Tags: php, html, directory, localhost, root

I am developing my first PHP webapp on localhost. I am unable to refer to files in my sub-directories. For example, from any page of my project, if I have to call the following page, the image doesn't appear.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page is Under Construction</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
            .imgcontainer {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
                position: center;
            }



            </style>

        <div class="imgcontainer" style="padding:0px;">
            <img src="/myProjectRootFolder/images/under-construction.png"  alt=""/>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The error message on Console is

```
UnderConstruction.php:25 GET http://localhost/myProjectRootFolder/images/under-construction.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: if your page is under myProjectRootFolder then you just need to call   <img src="images/under-construction.png"  alt=""/>

depending upon your location of the image folder. this will only work if image folder is inside myProjectRootFolder

Comment: give your full details of your sub directories and your image location in localhost

Answer (score 2):

could be you need  a relative path

```
  <img src="./myProjectRootFolder/images/under-construction.png"  alt=""/>
```

or

```
  <img src="./images/under-construction.png"  alt=""/>
```

and be sure of your real image and pathnames ..

if your url for invoke the page is

```
 /myProjectRootFolder/summary/salessummary.php
```

you should use the relative path

```
<img src="../images/under-construction.png"  alt=""/>
```

then you should use

Comment: I am using Google Chrome on Win 7 x64. The suggest code is also not giving the result

Comment: also the second one ..??

Comment: `/myProjectRootFolder/summary/salessummary.php`

Comment: In the instant problem, the `underconstruction.php` is not able to locate the `.png` file

Comment: Thank you got it.